# Python function variable scope, calling script within function in another script

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 scripts: MA_ExecFast  MA_BacktestFast and MA_OptimizationFast
originally I have functions of MA_ExecFast  MA_BacktestFast in the same script for prototyping.

I have:

```
def MA_Exec(start_date= default_date, MA_length = default_length):
    global SignalTable
    global PositionTable
    PositionData = PositionTable[-1:]
    Signal = Ticker.loc[Ticker.Date < start_date][-(MA_length + 1):]

def backTest():
    global PositionTable
    OldPosition = PositionTable[-1:]
    NewSig = SignalTable[-1:]   #Last row of SignalTable
    Backtest = pd.concat([OldPosition,NewSig], ignore_index=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    col1 = [...]
    col2 = [...]
    SignalTable = pd.DataFrame(columns = col1)
    PositionTable = pd.DataFrame(columns = col1 + col2)
    start_date = date(2016, 8, 15)
    end_date = date(2017, 8, 15)
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        MA_Exec(start_date=single_date, MA_length = 20)
        backTest()
```

But now I need to put these function to different scripts. I want to call the first two scripts in MA_OptimizationFast:

```
import MA_BacktestFast
import MA_ExecFas

def Opt(start_date = default_start_date, end_date = default_end_date, start_MA_length = default_start_Var1, end_MA_length = default_end_Var1):
    col1 = [...]
    col3 = [...]
    for length in range(start_MA_length, end_MA_length + 1): # Loop through different MA_length
        SignalTable = pd.DataFrame(columns = col1)
        PositionTable = pd.DataFrame(columns = col3)
        for single_date in MA_BacktestFast.daterange(start_date, end_date):  # Loop through different dates with the same MA_length
            MA_ExecFast.MA_Exec(start_date=single_date, MA_length = length)
            MA_BacktestFast.backTest()
        # After each MA_length is finished, we read the final return of this MA_length
        ReturnTable = PositionTable
```

Now when I run Opt(), I will get `NameError: name 'PositionTable' is not defined.`
I know the reason is that, PositionTable and SignalTable are now in Opt() function so they are no longer global variables, but if I simply remove the global keyword in function MA_Exec() and backTest(). It still won't work. I guess that's because this makes SignalTable and PositionTable local variable of those two functions.

I want the SignalTable and PositionTable variable location as they are right now because I want to clear the Dataframe in each outer for loop. How can I make the outer for loop layer as the old "global" layer?

Comment: It is bad naming, I will change it, I didn't mean to return anything

Comment: All the way through, I was looking for a PEP8 table to summarise naming convention but potentially it only exists for Google convention. You mix `global` in there too, which I see no reason for. I'm trying to trace down your issue but those discrepancies are really distracting.

Comment: @Dylan You can use [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) instead of `global`, but really you should be using them as function / return parameters instead. Otherwise that code is a mess.